# Javascript: JSON parse without overwriting existing key

Tags: javascript, json

I was given a JSON file that has duplicate key with the second one being a null value as follows:

`var jsonString = '{"dup": 1, "dup": null}';`

When doing `JSON.parse(jsonString)`, "dup" becomes "null".

What I need though, is to keep the "dup" equals to "1" if the second "dup" is null. So I was wondering if there are any functions like:

`var noNullJson = jsonString.removeNull(); 
JSON.parse(noNullJson);   //{"dup": 1}`

Or if there is any function in Javascript that does not allow overwriting the key when calling `JSON.parse`.

Thanks for taking to read this question. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not try with a well-formed json, without duplicated keys ?

Comment: Where did that JSON came from? Can you influence its construction?

Comment: JSON with duplicate keys is valid, but suggested to avoid.

Comment: I can't really change the design because this seemingly weird overwriting strategy seems to be applied everywhere in our structure. I thought it might be better if I could manage it from the front end to reduce potential inaccuracies on the other parts of the system. Fixing the root of the problem is a bit beyond my limit now..

Answer (score 2):

I have written a function which will remove null and parse the json.
Most of the permutation I tried with this approach.

you can run code, also here i have given 4 test-cases of different models.

hope, this will help.

[P.S. this logic only works for `Flat JSONs` (JSONs without nested Object)]

```js
function removeNullAndParseJson(jsonString) {
    var commaSplitedArr = jsonString.split(','),
     finalSplittedArr = [];
    commaSplitedArr.forEach(function(d, index){
     if(d.indexOf('null') !== -1){
      if(index === 0){
       finalSplittedArr.push(d.replace(/[^{}\[\].]/g, ""));
      }else {
       finalSplittedArr[finalSplittedArr.length-1] += d.replace(/[^{}\[\].]/g, "");
      }
     }else {
      finalSplittedArr.push(d);
     }
    });
    return JSON.parse(finalSplittedArr.map(function(d){return d.replace("{}", "");}).join(','));
}

//----Testing-----
var jsonString;

//test case1
jsonString = '{"dup": 1, "dup": null}';
console.log('test1 -- ', removeNullAndParseJson(jsonString));

//test case2
jsonString = '[{"dup": 1, "dup": null}, {"dup": 2, "dup": null}]';
console.log('test2 -- ', removeNullAndParseJson(jsonString));


//test case3
jsonString = '[{"dup": 1, "dup": null}, {"dup": 2, "dup": null}, {"dup": null, "dup": null}]';
console.log('test3 -- ', removeNullAndParseJson(jsonString));


//test case4
jsonString = '[{"dup": 1, "dup": null}, {"dup": null, "dup": null}, {"dup": 2, "dup": null}]';
console.log('test4 -- ', removeNullAndParseJson(jsonString));
```

Comment: This seems to break when I have a nested object though: `jsonString = '[{"Key":"2522","Value":{"foo":{"a":null,"b":false,"c":2}}}]';`

Comment: yes. It is breaking for `JSON` with nested object.
will add a note to the solution. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You might try renaming it before parsing like;

```js
var jsonString = '{"dup": 1, "dup": null}',
          jObj = JSON.parse(jsonString.replace(/(dup).+(\1)/,"$&" + "2"));
console.log(jObj);
```